# How do I list ALL categories, even unchecked ones, from the Post field in Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I have a predicament. I am trying to create a menu on a page in which it lists ALL the categories, not just the one the specific post is assigned to. For example, I have 4 categories (category1, category2, category3, category4) and I would like to display all of them on a list on the side menu. However, for the article I'm on, this article only has category1 assigned to it.

I looked at all Wordpress snippets and all of them only returns the category that is actually checked off in the backend of the post.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
     $cats = get_terms('category', array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'exclude' => '1'
     ));
     ?>

    <?php foreach($cats as $cat): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat); ?>"><?php echo get_cat_name($cat); ?></a></li><br />
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code excludes the "unorganized" category, hence the exclude 1, but once again it only gives me the categories that are listed. can someone help? I also tried get_the_category() and get_the_category_list() as well and both of them didn't give me the unchecked ones. Thanks!

Comment: In your array try to add - hide_empty => false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify in the arguments passed to the `get_terms()` function not to hide empty categories.

[More about `get_terms()`.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Try this:

```
$cats = get_terms('category', array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'exclude' => '1',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [get_categories()?](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

You can supply arguments to it, like exclude. I am assuming it would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'exclude' => '1' 
);

$cats = get_categories($args);
```